# Does Office 365 REST API python client have inbuilt anti malware?

Tags: python, sharepoint, office365api

Iam using this Python package to read files from SharePoint.
Does this package have inbuilt anti malware so that it automatically ignores files with malware?

Comment: Even if it does you should treat it like it doesn't. Never trust any input/download data. They could have 5 pages explaining how they keep you safe, and not one of those pages is a guarantee that you are safe. Consider that anything they do to keep you safe is in their API for all to see.